# How do I merge multiple records in Access 2007 into a single record?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I've searched through numerous discussions and have been unable to find a solution to my particular problem.  I have an Access 2007 database with a Faculty table and Sessions table in a many-to-many relationship.  Faculty members can be in more than one session and can have different roles (presenter, moderator, facilitator, etc.) depending on which session you look at.  I am trying to create a query that lists a faculty member's roles in a single record across all the sessions they are in.  Currently, I get a single record for each session that a faculty member is in unless their roles are identical in another session.  I want to see their roles across the board independent of the sessions they are in.

I'm part of the way there.  Below is the SQL code for the query I currently have.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  FacultySessionJoin.FacultyID, 
  Faculty.FirstName, 
  Faculty.LastName, 
  Faculty.Email, 
  FacultySessionJoin.Presenter, 
  FacultySessionJoin.Moderator, 
  FacultySessionJoin.Facilitator
FROM 
  Faculty 
LEFT JOIN 
  FacultySessionJoin ON Faculty.FacultyID = FacultySessionJoin.FacultyID
ORDER BY FacultySessionJoin.FacultyID;
```

I'd post an image of the results, but the site won't allow me to.  Here's an example of my problem:

```
Faculty ID  FirstName  LastName  Presenter  Moderator  Facilitator
3            Vanessa    Smith      Yes         
3            Vanessa    Smith      Yes        Yes
```

How would I combine all such records in my query into a single line such as:

```
Faculty ID  FirstName  LastName  Presenter  Moderator  Facilitator
3            Vanessa    Smith      Yes        Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT 
   FacultySessionJoin.FacultyID, 
   Faculty.FirstName, Faculty.LastName, 
   Faculty.Email, 
   Max(FacultySessionJoin.Presenter), 
   Max(FacultySessionJoin.Moderator), 
   Max(FacultySessionJoin.Facilitator)
FROM Faculty 
LEFT JOIN FacultySessionJoin 
ON Faculty.FacultyID = FacultySessionJoin.FacultyID
GROUP BY 
   FacultySessionJoin.FacultyID, Faculty.FirstName, 
   Faculty.LastName, Faculty.Email
```

Comment: That solution does return only one record per faculty in the query results, but the values that are returned are not correct.

Comment: In that case, you will need to post enough sample data for a proper test. A small section from both tables will be enough. The SQL above returns the required result based on the information supplied in your original post.